# How to make a copy constructor for a Linked List

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linked-list, copy-constructor

Ok so I'm trying to make a copy constructor for a linked list. I know how to a copy constructor for an array but not for a linked list. Can somebody give me an idea on how I can do this and thanks.

```
class node 
{


public :

    double data;  
    node *next;  /// pointer that points to next elemnt
    node () { next = NULL; data = 0; }
    node (double val ) { next = NULL; data = val; }

private:



};
```

queue header

```
class linked_queue
{


public :

    linked_queue() { front = NULL; back = NULL; ctr = 0;  }   /// default constructor
    bool _empty();  
    void _size();   
    void _front();   
    void _back();   
    void _push(double); 
    void pop();  
    void _display();   
    ~linked_queue(); /// destructor
    linked_queue& operator= ( const linked_queue& rhs );
    linked_queue( const linked_queue& other );

private :

    int  ctr; /// counter
    node  *front;  /// front pointer
    node *back;  ///back pointer

};
```

Edit : This is what i came up with

linked_queue::linked_queue( const linked_queue& other )
{

```
ctr = 0;
front = NULL;
back = NULL;

node *p = other.front;

while ( p != NULL )
{
    _push( p->data);
    p = p->next;
}
```

}

Comment: How about going through all the items in the original list and adding them to your new list?

Comment: Would I create a new pointer and set it equal to front and traverse the list and copy all the data from the original to front

Comment: I mean new list not front

Comment: Start by initializing your `linked_queue` like you were creating an empty one, then go through each node of your original list and call `_push(node_ptr->data);`

Comment: Ohh I get you thanks Cato!

Comment: I have updated the question with a supposed solution

Answer (score 0):

Just walk through the list, allocate a bunch of nodes with the same values, and set the `next` pointers.  Finally, set the `front` and `back` pointers and `ctr`, and you're done.

Comment: Should I start by making a new node pointer, and set it to front and copy all the data from original to the new pointer

Comment: You are probably better off following Vaughn Cato's advice from the Question comments section.  That way you're less likely to do something silly by accident.